# Default button on enter and popup list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm trying to implement a form with multiple buttons on it. When I press enter I want to have my default button submitted. This code from http://greatwebguy.com/programming/dom/default-html-button-submit-on-enter-with-jquery/ generally works:

```
$(function() {
$("form input").keypress(function (e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
        $('button[type=submit].default').click();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

});

but...
when I type in input field I have an autocomplete popup so when I press enter in this popup I expect to put this value to input field, not submit all form. Can I check somehow if this enter comes from popup? Or I should try to do this different way?

EDIT:
I think I didn't say it clear. This popup is not any part of jquery. It's standard popup that shows previously typed data into input. So it hasn't got any class nor id. Stop propagation  doesn't work either. None of solutions below resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code and it works now.
I have an enum called Operation in my command and I set different value of the field before every submit button eg:

```
<input type="submit" value="do sth" onclick="setOperationAndSubmit('DO_STH')"/>
<input type="submit" value="next" onclick="setOperationAndSubmit('DEFAULT')"/>

function setOperationAndSubmit(operation) {
    if (document.myForm.elements['operation'].value === '') {
        document.myForm.elements['operation'].value = operation;
    }
    document.myForm.submit();
}
```

Then I have my action that listens to keypress and it set appropriate operation on every enter key:

```
$(function() {
    $("form input").keypress(function(e) {
        if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
            document.myForm.elements['operation'].value = 'DEFAULT';
        }
    });
});
```

so default action is executed when I press enter

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:visible` to see if the dropdown `div` for the autocomplete is open, and then prevent the enter key action of your code completing. Something like this:

```
$("form input").keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key == 13 && !$(".autocomplete").is(":visible")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

You could also use `event.stopPropagation()` on the enter key press in the autocomplete function, however you'll probably have to amend the source manually which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Before `return false;`

write

`e.preventDefault();`

or/and

`e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("form input").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.target.id !== "autoCompliteId" && ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13))) {
                    $('button[type=submit].default').click();

                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```